# codeigniter error pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to access helpers/libraries in error pages of codeigniter ?
For example error_general ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function:

```
$CI &= get_instance();
$CI->load->library('foo');
```

Comment: $CI->load->helper('url');, redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');. Check http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. This worked for me. However, the statement should actually say this,

```
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->load->library('foo');
```